# bash--wildcard of [characters]

Tags: bash

Is there a way to use `[characters]`, such as `[:upper:]`, as if they were a wildcard? for example, lets say I have a directory with the following files:

```
AAA
AA
aaa
aa
BBB
BB
bbb
bb
```

now lets say I want to `ls` all the files that start with AT LEAST two lowercase letters. Instead of `ls [[:lower]][[:lower:]]*` is there a more efficient way of doing this, which would be essentially be "wildcard number of `[[:lower:]]`'s and then a wildcard?"

Also, what about not just starting with two lowercase letters, but starting with ONLY 2 lowercase letters, not * lowercase letters. (i.e. `?` instead of `*`)? thanks

Comment: what about doing an alias on your `.bashrc` ?, something like `alias lsl="ls | grep -E '^([a-z]{2,})'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. In the
>   following description, a *pattern-list* is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a ‘`|`’. Composite patterns may be formed using
>   one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ?(*pattern-list*)
>   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
>
> *(*pattern-list*)
>   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> +(*pattern-list*)
>   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> @(*pattern-list*)
>   Matches one of the given patterns.
>
> !(*pattern-list*)
>   Matches anything except one of the given patterns.

As for what you asked, I can't make sense of this one:

> ... all the files that start with AT LEAST two lowercase letters ... "wildcard number of [[:lower:]]'s and then a wildcard?"

A wildcard matches zero or more, which is not the same as two-or-more. Any number of `[[:lower:]]`s can be matched with the extended glob `*([[:lower:]])`. "At least two" doesn't need extended globbing at all: `[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]*`.

> ... starting with ONLY 2 lowercase letters, not * lowercase letters

```
[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]?([^[:lower:]]*)
```

Which is two lowercase characters optionally followed by (anything other than a lowercase character and anything).